# How to use aliases defined in .bashrc in other scripts?

Tags: bash, alias

In ~/.bashrc, I defined some aliases. But I cannot use them in other shell scripts, where I can only use aliases defined right there. Even though I sourced bashrc, it still did not work. What should I do?

PS. I'm in bash.

Comment: Regarding what drewrobb alluded to, as a way of keeping these aliases separate from the rest of the things in your `.bashrc` script, you may also wish to isolate your aliases into their own file (e.g. `$HOME/.aliases` or something), and `shopt` and `source` it from both your other shell script and your `.bashrc`.  This would avoid possible side effects from other things in `.bashrc`, while still keeping them in a single place for easy maintenance.

Comment: Or else if you can avoid spawning a sub-shell by executing . ./my-script.sh then all the aliases set in .bashrc are available to your script without any extra setting.

Comment: It works with a additional alias-file! But why doesn't it work with the bashrc?

Comment: Not sure offhand, and probably can't tell without seeing your `.bashrc.`  This is a better solution anyway.

Comment: You don't; `.bashrc` sets up the environment for your interactive shells. Shell scripts should not depend on that.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You need to do `shopt -s expand_aliases` in the script in addition to sourcing `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: And how about if the script can not be modified?

Comment: @iuliux: Define and export functions instead. Let's say your script uses `mv` without `-i` or `-v` and you want to add them, but can't modify the script. `function mv () { command mv -iv "$@"; }; export -f mv` Now your script will use those options. This is why well written scripts use absolute paths to executables (e.g. `/bin/mv`). It will prevent this technique from working and is good security practice. Please post your question as a new question and I'll post this as an answer to it.

Answer (score 12):

The simplest answer is to do the 2 important things or it wont' work.

```
#!/bin/bash -i

# Expand aliases defined in the shell ~/.bashrc
shopt -s expand_aliases
```

After this, your aliases that you have defined in ~/.bashrc they will be available in your shell script (giga.sh or any.sh) and to any function or child shell within such script.

If you don't do that, you'll get an error:

```
your_cool_alias: command not found
```

Comment: Hi! The `shopt -s expand_aliases` line seems like no effect _for me_. It was actually enough the `#!/bin/bash -i` line without the `shopt -s expand_aliases` line when I executed the script with `./script.sh` inside the graphical terminal (kde Konsole). Similarly, it was running script with `bash -i script.sh` , i.e. interactively (with -i) instead of `bash script.sh` that worked without both the two lines. Although I did not find a way to execute the script with `bash script.sh`  (both lines don't help).

Answer (score 5):

`.bashrc` is meant for one purpose: to configure the environment for your interactive shells. If you have code that you want shared between your `.bashrc` and other scripts, then it belongs in a separate file that is sourced by *each* of your `.bashrc` and shell script.

Comment: ... And simply don't use an alias for that; create a shell function or a standalone script.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem and I reloaded the file with this command to fix it.

```
$ source ~/.bashrc
```

Answer (score 1):

Stolen from [enzotib](https://askubuntu.com/users/2647/enzotib) on ask ubuntu: Alias are deprecated in favor of shell functions. From `bash` manual page:

> For almost every purpose, aliases are superseded by shell functions.

To create a function, and export it to subshells, put the following in your `~/.bashrc`:

```
petsc() {
    ~/petsc-3.2-p6/petsc-arch/bin/mpiexec "$@"
}
export -f petsc
```

Then you can freely call your command from your scripts.

Comment: Have any references saying aliases are/will be deprecated out of bash? That can't be right.

Comment: The quote above is from the man page on OS X. It says "supersede" and I said "deprecated." Maybe its a matter of wording, but it sounds like they're not the preferred way to do things.

Comment: The Debian man page says the same thing, I'm not sure but I thought the line meant if an alias and a function had the same name, the function would take priority, but it doesn't (can't create a function with the same name as an alias, but can create an alias with a function's name and then only the alias "runs") so it's a little vague. The "deprecated" word did stand out, as in "this feature is deprecated and will be removed in later versions" which doesn't appear to be the case for aliases

Answer (score 0):

There is a way of doing it globally without adding lines to each script you execute: by using the `BASH_ENV` variable.

Here is my setup for OS X 10.8.5:

/etc/launchd.conf:

```
setenv BASH_ENV /Users/DK/.env
```

~/.bash_profile:

```
# == Bash setup for interactive shells ==    
# === Environment for all shells ===
. $BASH_ENV    
# [skipped]
```

~/.env:

```
# == Setup for all shells ==
# This is executed for all interactive and for non-interactive shells (e.g. scripts)

shopt -s expand_aliases extglob xpg_echo

# [skipped] Misc. variables and PATH setup

# === General aliases ===

alias pause='echo "Press [Return] or [Enter] to continue..."; read' # read -p does not display prompt in Eclipse console

# [skipped]
```