# Set alias within bash script

Tags: bash

I'm trying to create an alias in a script like so:

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s expand_aliases

#Currently just using 'git' to try and get it working
#It'll be replaced with the following line when it works
#compgen -c | while read x;
echo 'git' | while read x;
  do
    a=`echo $x | tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]'`;
    echo $a;
    echo $x;
    if [ "$a" != '' ]
    then
      echo 'got here';
      alias $a=$x;
      alias;
      GIT;
    fi
done
```

While a simple test script works (`testme` is added to the aliases in my current shell):

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s expand_aliases
alias testme="echo It Worked"
alias
testme
```

Output from first script:

```
GIT
git
got here
alias GIT='git'
alias grep='grep --colour=auto'
alias ls='ls --color=auto'
GIT: command not found
```

`GIT` shows up in the aliases, but can't be executed.  I've tried calling it with `. ./script.sh` and `source script.sh`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you should not rely on aliases in script. you should use variable directly. but if you still want the alias maybe this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240755/how-to-use-aliases-defined-in-bashrc-in-shell-script

Comment: The whole point of the script is to *set* the alias, not run it.  It's a bit useless, but it's fun!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's likely a problem of *when* the alias is expanded.  The bash man page has the following to say:

> The rules concerning the definition and use of aliases are somewhat
>   confusing.  Bash always reads at  least  one complete  line  of input before executing any of the commands on that line.  Aliases are expanded when a command
>          is read, not when it is executed. ...

There's more info in the man page, but when executing a compound statement such as the list within your `while` loop, the expansion will occur when when the input is first read, not when executed.  Since `GIT` is not defined when the input is read, there will be an error.

The following snippet shows the issue:

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s expand_aliases

while read x; do
    a=`echo $x | tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]'`
    alias $a=$x
    GIT   # <--- this fails to execute git
done < <(echo 'git')

GIT # <--- this executes git
```

Once the while loop has executed, then the alias becomes available.  Details in the man page are a bit sketchy, but it appears as though the comments for aliases defined in functions would apply.

Also, be careful when using syntax such as `echo foo | while read x; do stuff; done`.  The `while` loop will execute in a subshell, any changes made in the subshell will not persist beyond the `while` loop.  The example above shows a method so that the while loop executes in the current shell, but takes its input from a command which is executed.

**Update:**

If the above script were written in its original form it would look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s expand_aliases

#Currently just using 'git' to try and get it working
#It'll be replaced with the following line when it works
#compgen -c | while read x;

echo 'git' | while read x; do
    a=`echo $x | tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]'`
    alias $a=$x
    GIT   # <--- this fails to execute git
done

GIT # <--- this also fails executes git because the alias' were set in a subshell.
```

In this case, the alias is never executed.  The reason for this is that the pipe `|` stars a new subshell and links the processes together.  The `echo` runs in one process, the `while read ...` runs in the other, linked by a pipe.  When the aliases are set, they are set in the environment of the process of the subshell running the `while` loop.  However, when the `while` loop has finished, that process terminates and its environment is discarded, along with any changes made to its environment such as the addition of aliases.  As a result, the second attempt to execute `GIT` will fail as the alias information has been discarded.

When you use the topology shown in the first script, the `while` loops runs in the current script, so any changes made to the environment persist past the end of the loop.

You will also notice this behaviour if you *execute* your script, rather than sourcing it.  If you expect to be able to configure a set of aliases in a script like this, run the script, have them available in your environment, you have the same problem because your script runs in a separate process to the parent shell, creates the aliases, which are subsequently discarded when the script exits.

```
$ ./create_aliases
$ alias  # <--- Ooops, no aliases defined.
```

You'd have to source your script like this, which will run the contents of the script in the current process, thus modifying the current environment.

```
$ source ./create_aliases
$ alias # <--- Yay, new aliases present.
```

This is why bash will source files such as `~/.bashrc`, so that changes you make in that file will exist in the current environment.

Comment: Excellent!  I thought it might have something to do with sub-shells but couldn't figure out how (Very new to bash scripting).  Could you explain a bit more on how `< <(echo 'git')` causes the `while` to be executed in the current shell?