# alias not recognized in while read line loop in UNIX

Tags: unix

Here is sample code:

```
    while IFS= read var
    do
    shopt -s expand_aliases
    alias fin="cd /directory/"
    fin
    done
```

Result:

```
    script.sh: line 53: fin: command not found
```

I am using `var` in other command. My concern here is that, after running script the error occurs.

Comment: It's explained in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15916457/3691891

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set alias within bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15915684/set-alias-within-bash-script)