# Import a path defined in bashrc to perl script

Tags: perl, path, environment-variables

I've defined a path (say, $MYPAT) in .bashrc file and I would like to use it in perl scripts, so that inside the script I just can write `open(IN, "<$MYPAT/dir1/..`. How can I import this variable to directly use it in my script?

I guess is the same problem posted here [How to use aliases defined in .bashrc in shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240755/how-to-use-aliases-defined-in-bashrc-in-shell-script) but applied to perl.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `$MYPAT` is an environment variable defined in your .bashrc, you can access it using the special `%ENV` hash in perl, which contains all the environment variables for your process. See `%ENV` in [perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html).

```
my $path = $ENV{MYPAT};
```

Also, as a stylistic note:

1. You should use lexical filehandles instead of globals
2. You should use the three-argument form of open.

So instead of

```
open(IN, "<$path/dir1/...")
```

make that

```
open my $fh, '<', "$path/dir1/..." or die "yadda yadda";
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I would apply your note. In case of using `open my $fh, '<',...` should I change `while(<IN>){` to `while(<>){`?

Comment: Change it to `while(<$fh>)`

Answer (score 1):

There are so many modules for every work to make it possible.
I think this module in CPAN would be helpful for you, just go through a little documentation.

```
Shell::Source
```